# How to get the newest address for each person

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a simple Access database an example of table structure and a query.  Two tables, person(contains 3 records) & address(contains 5 records), provide the ability to capture multiple addresses for each person.  I am good with normal conditional statements, but this one is throwing me for a loop...
I am looking for a query that will return only the newest address for a given person.
[Table Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KcKw.jpg)

Current sql for the query:

```
SELECT Person.PersonID_PK, Address.Address, Address.StatusDate
FROM Person INNER JOIN Address ON Person.[PersonID_PK] = Address.PersonID_FK;
```

My current returns:

```
EmployeeID_PK  Address                         StatusDate
1               12 Elm St, MN  23569            11/13/2017
1               15 Apple Ln, NY 12345           7/15/2018
2               30 Mulberry, TN 38456           6/11/2018
2               10 Lonesome Pine, KY 15487      12/4/2018
3               100 Plaze Place, LA 14563       6/17/2018
```

I need to return each person along with the greatest(newest) StatusDate
My expected return should be:

```
EmployeeID_PK  Address                             StatusDate
1               15 Apple Ln, NY 12345                7/15/2018
2               10 Lonesome Pine, KY 15487           12/4/2018
3               100 Plaze Place, LA 14563            6/17/2018
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from address as a
where a.statusdate = (select max(a2.statusdate)
                      from address as a2
                      where a2.EmployeeID_PK = a.EmployeeID_PK
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE with a ranking function works neatly.

```
;WITH empaddress AS 
( 
           SELECT     person.personid_pk, 
                      address.address, 
                      address.statusdate, 
                      Dense_rank() OVER (partition BY id ORDER BY statusdate DESC) AS d_rank 
           FROM       person 
           INNER JOIN address 
           ON         person.[PersonID_PK] = address.personid_fk; ) 
SELECT person.personid_pk, 
       address.address, 
       address.statusdate 
FROM   empaddress 
WHERE  d_rank = 1;
```

Comment: Does someone want to count the number of ways that MS Access doesn't support this query?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I modified Gordon's code to support my query, the following provided the answer.

```
SELECT Person.PersonID_PK, Address.Address, Address.StatusDate
FROM Person 
INNER JOIN Address 
ON Person.[PersonID_PK] = Address.PersonID_FK
WHERE (((Address.StatusDate)=(SELECT MAX(Address.StatusDate)
FROM Address
WHERE Person.PersonID_PK = Address.PersonID_FK)));
```